# Set of irrationals between two reals is uncountable

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, irrational-numbers

I know that between any two reals, there is an irrational number.

See: [Proving that there exists an irrational number in between any given real numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87729/proving-that-there-exists-an-irrational-number-in-between-any-given-real-numbers)

Now let a, b $\in$ $R$ such that a < b. And let M be the set of irrationals between a and b.

I want to show that M is uncountable. To do this, I think I need to show that there does not exist a bijection from M to the natural numbers.

1. Can someone give me a hint about how to start to show this?
2. What's the best way to approach "non-existence" proofs in general?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered simply using a bijection from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb R$?  Like, say, $\tan x$?

Comment: If you subtract a countable set from an uncountable one, what remains is uncountable. Any interval $(a,b)$ is uncountable, and the rationals are countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you know that the interval $(a, b)$ is uncountable and that the set of rational numbers in that interval is countable. So the problem reduces to the following:

*If $Y \subseteq X$ are sets such that $X$ is uncountable and $Y$ is countable, then $Z = X \mathrel{\backslash} Y$ is uncountable.*

To see this, note that $Z$ is either (a) finite, (b) countably infinite or (c) uncountable. But the union of a finite set (or a countably infinite set) and a countable set is countable so (a) and (b) can't hold. So (c) holds, which was what we wanted.

Comment: A bit harder is to prove that in fact $(a,b)\setminus \mathbb Q$ has the same size as $(a,b)$. (This does not require the axiom of choice.)

Comment: @Andres Caicedo: indeed, let's hope the OP enjoys the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem when he or she gets to it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead you could show that there is a bijection between this set and interval (0,1)

Comment: Is this the standard way to show a set is uncountable?

Comment: As far as I know: yes. As you have probably noticed when trying to solve this problem, to show "non-existence" directly can be tricky.

Comment: @Alex: What bijection between the set of *irrational* numbers in the interval $(a, b)$ and the set of *all* numbers in the interval $(a, b)$ are you proposing the OP should use?

Comment: I didn't say that the proof should one-step procedure. The bijection could be between the interval (a,b) and (0,1), and then additional argument about countability of rationals on both of the intervals.

Comment: @Alex: your comment reduces the problem to the special case when $a = 0$ and $b = 1$, without actually solving the problem.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. First, the main purpose of my answer here was to tell OP to try another approach to the problem: instead of showing that there is no bijection to naturals, show that there is a bijection to a set that is known to be uncountable. It seems like kbball understood it. Second, bijection between $(a,b)$ and $(0, 1)$ is there to see that we can consider $(0,1)$ without loss of generality.

Comment: I don't understand how you plan to complete the proof in a way such that your suggestion results in a simplification. The obvious bijection between $(a,b)$ and $(0,1)$ does not map rationals to rationals (unless $a$ and $b$ happen to be rationals.)

Answer (score 2):

First,
show that there is a
*rational* number
between any two reals.

This can be done using the
Archimedean axiom
(or theorem depending on your
axioms)
that,
for any two positive reals
$x$ and $y$,
there is an integer $n$
such that
$nx > y$.

Then,
using the same reasoning,
show that there is *another* rational
between the two reals.

Let these rationals be
$r$ and $s$.

Finally,
construct a linear mapping
from $[0, 1]$
to $[r, s]$.
This mapping maps rationals to rationals
and irrationals to irrationals.

Since there an uncountable number of irrationals
in $[0, 1]$,
there are an uncountable number of irrationals
in $[r, s]$.

Another proof,
this time by contradiction,
 can be modeled on
Cantor's original proof that
the reals are uncountable,
but I'll leave that as an exercise.