# Proving that an irrational number exists near every rational number

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that arbitrarly close to any rational number there is a real (non-rational) number. In other words, show that to each real $\varepsilon>0$ and each rational $r\in\mathbb Q$ there exists $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ with $\left|x-r\right|\lt\varepsilon  $

No idea how to prove this one. Perhaps I can define some sort of sequence and show it converges...?

Comment: Do you know that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational? Using some arithmetic and the Archimedian property of the reals you can extract a number related to $\sqrt{2}$ between any two rational numbers.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87729/proving-that-there-exists-an-irrational-number-in-between-any-given-real-numbers or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46822/density-of-irrationals and who knows how many more questions here.

Comment: Since there is a rational between any two reals, given any $a<b$ there is a rational between $a+\sqrt2$ and $b+\sqrt2$. Now, subtract $\sqrt2$ from all three numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every $n\in\mathbb N$ you have

$$\sqrt2\notin \mathbb Q \Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{n\sqrt2}\notin\mathbb Q$$

Now let $\varepsilon >0$, then $n$ can be found such that

$$\dfrac{1}{n\sqrt2} \lt \varepsilon$$

Now for arbitrary $r\in\mathbb Q$ and given $\varepsilon>0$ chose $x=r+\dfrac{1}{n\sqrt2}\notin\mathbb Q$

$$\left|x-r\right| = \left| r+\frac{1}{n\sqrt2}-r\right|= \dfrac{1}{n\sqrt2} \lt \varepsilon $$

Comment: these types of proofs always make sense to me but confuse me too:

"Now let $\epsilon > 0$, then $n$ can be found such that"

is this an obvious fact? how do we know that? I'm never sure of what is needed to be proven or not in these sorts of things

Comment: @terribleatmath For any real number $r$ there is a natural number $n$ such that $n>r$, so the statement in my proof can be reformulated as: "there is an $n$ such that $n> \dfrac{1}{\varepsilon\sqrt2}$"

Comment: To find such an $n$ you just have to "round up" to the next integer

Comment: it may seem like a silly question, but how did you get fromm the second to last step to the last step? mainly, the absolute value sign?

Comment: I'am not sure what exactly you mean with your question, but I made a little edit. Is it more clear now?

Comment: yes it is, thank you.

Comment: you're welcome.

Comment: I understand all of this really well, I just have a lot of trouble getting started. we chose epsilon arbitrarily small and we showed that we can always find an x (irrational number) so close to any rational r that the distance is less than this epsilon.

this makes PERFECT sense to me, i just see a question like this and never know where to begin, I guess i just need more practice and exposure.

Answer (score 1):

Let $q$ be rational. Let $a_n = q-1/(n\cdot\pi)$. This sequence converges to $q$ and consists of irrationals only.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ If not there exists a nonempty interval $I$ containing only rationals. Repeatedly shifting $I$ left or right by a fixed  rational less  than the length of $I$ covers the real line with rationals, so $\,\Bbb R = \Bbb Q.$

Answer (score 0):

If it weren't true, then you could find an open interval around a rational number which contains only rational numbers. But this contradicts the countability of the rationals, since every interval of positive length contains uncountably many points.

Comment: this makes sense, but 2 things: we haven't talked about open intervlas in the class yet so i'm not sure I could use that, and we're to prove it the way set out in this problem, the convergence to this $\epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

$\pi$ is irrational, so also $k\pi$ is irrational for any rational $k$. Find any number $a<\epsilon/\pi$. If $a$ is irrational, $r+a$ is also irrational. If $a$ is rational, $r+\pi a$ is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

Say they give you a rational $q$, and you are to show that there is an irrational $r$ nearer than $\epsilon$ from $q$. Select $n$ natural such that $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$, then $q + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2 n}$ is irrational, and between $q$ and $q + \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be an irrational and $n$ a positive integer, then
$$
nx-1<\lfloor nx\rfloor\le nx
$$
and thus
$$
x-\frac{1}{n}<\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{n}\le x
$$
This means that within $\dfrac{1}{n}$ away from $x$ there is arational $\dfrac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{n}$

In particular, if we want the difference less that $\varepsilon>0$, we first note that if
$$
n=\left\lfloor\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\right\rfloor+1,
$$
then
$$
n>\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \quad \Longrightarrow\quad \varepsilon >\frac{1}{n},
$$ 
and hence
$$
x-\varepsilon<x-\frac{1}{n}<\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{n}=\frac{m}{n}\le x.
$$