# Function continuous only in a point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, continuity

Is true that the  function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$f(t):=\begin{cases}t \: , \: t\in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q} \\
0\: , t\in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$

is continuous only in the point $0$ ?

If the answer is yes, how I can prove the assertion?

Comment: Yeah, it is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty easy to show that $f$ is continuous at $0$. For any $x_0 \neq 0$, by Bolzano-Weierstrass any neighbourhood of $x_0$ has two limit points, so $f$ is not continuous anywhere else.

If you don't want to use Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, assume that $f$ is continuous at $0 \neq x_0 \in \mathbb{Q}$. That is,
$$ \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0\mid |x-x_0| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(x_0)| = |f(x)| < \epsilon
$$
However, [inbetween every two real number there exists an irrational number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87729/proving-that-there-exists-an-irrational-number-in-between-any-given-real-numbers), so another $x'\mid |x' - x_0| < \delta$ exists with $|f(x')| \geq \epsilon$ when $\epsilon$ is smaller than $x'$. Therefore $f$ is not continuous at any rational $x_0$.

Similarly $f$ is not continuous at any two irrational numbers [since](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421580/is-there-a-rational-number-between-any-two-irrationals)