# Prove that $\forall a,b {\in} \mathbb{Q} \:\:\exists x {\in}\mathbb{R}{\setminus} \mathbb{Q}\:\:a \lt x \lt b$

Tags: real-numbers

I'm trying to use cardinalities to prove that $$\forall a,b {\in} \mathbb{Q} \:\:\exists x {\in}\mathbb{R}{\setminus} \mathbb{Q}\:\:a \lt x \lt b.$$ Is the following proof of correct?

Let $ I = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} $

Assume $ \exists a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\left(\left(b \gt a\right) \land \forall x \in I\left(x \gt b\lor x \lt a\right)\right)$

Therefore, $ \left[a, b\right] \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \Rightarrow \left|\left[a, b\right]\right| \le \aleph_0$. However, $ \forall r,m \in \mathbb{R}\left(\left(r \lt m\right) \Rightarrow \left(\left|\left[r,m\right]\right| = \aleph\right)\right) $, and that is a contradiction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that there exists an irrational number in between any given real numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87729/proving-that-there-exists-an-irrational-number-in-between-any-given-real-numbers)

Comment: @DietrichBurde I've seen this proof, I'm trying to think of other ways to prove it

Comment: But your proof is the same idea, you are also using that the real numbers are not countable. So just look at Nana's proof at the duplicate.