# Understanding density of irrational numbers and Archemedian property

Tags: real-analysis

From

[Density of irrationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46822/density-of-irrationals)

I know this much of the proof of the density of irrational numbers

"We know that $y-x>0$. 
By the Archimedean property, there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $n(y-x)>1$ or $1/n < y-x$. There exists an integer $m$ such that $m \leq nx < m+1$ or $\displaystyle \frac{m}{n} \leq x \leq \frac{m+1}{n} < y$. "

Why does the following flow from the Archimedean property? As I know it the property states only what's above in the proof.

"Pick your favorite positive irrational, which is $\sqrt{2}$. By the Archimedean property, there exists $n$ such that $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\lt \frac{y-x}{2}$. Again by the Archimedean property, we know there exists an integer $m$ such that $m\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\right)\gt x$. Pick $M$ to be the *least* such $m$. Can you show that $M\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\right)$ is strictly between $x$ and $y$?
 (Above quote By Arturo Magidin)

I've seen the Archimedean property used similarly in this post 
 [Proof that the set of irrational numbers is dense in reals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935808/proof-that-the-set-of-irrational-numbers-is-dense-in-reals/935817#935817)

"By the density of rational numbers, there exists a rational number $r \in (x, y)$.

Since $\frac{y - r}{2} > 0$, by the Archimedian Property there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{y - r}{2} > \frac{1}{n}$. Then we have $x < r + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{n} < r + \frac{\sqrt{4}}{n} < y$. Now check that $s = r + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ is an irrational number sitting in $(x, y)$."(above proof written by Akech)

Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 2):

The Archimedean property in $\mathbb{R}$say that , for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ there exists an integer $n$ such that $n>x$.

As an immediate consequence we have that , given two real numbers $a, b$ with $a>0$,  there exists an integer $n$ such that $na>b$ (use the property with $x=b/a)$.

In your case you have : $b=1$ and $a=y-x$, so: $n(y-x)>1$.

Comment: Yes, I get that much, but how does it lead to "Pick your favorite positive irrational, which is $\sqrt{2}$. By the Archimedean property, there exists $n$ such that $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\lt \frac{y-x}{2}$. Again by the Archimedean property, we know there exists an integer $m$ such that $m\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\right)\gt x$."?

Comment: I've seen another poster also use $\frac{y-x}{2} $ as well, but. I haven't seen it in this form yet

Comment: The key fact is $na>b$ if $a\ne 0$. Chose $b=\sqrt{2}$ and $a=\frac{y-x}{2}$ ( with $y-x >0$) and you have the result.

Answer (score 0):

If $M$ is the least $m$
such that
$m\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\right)\gt x
$,
then
$(M-1)\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\right)
\le x
\lt M\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\right)
$.

Since
$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\lt \frac{y-x}{2}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
y
&\gt 2\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}+x\\
&\ge 2\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}+(M-1)\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\right)\\
&= 2\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}+M\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\right)-\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\right)\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}+M\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\right)\\
&\gt M\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

Actually,
it looks like
all that is needed is
$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}\lt y-x
$.